# Yammer Token Expiring

Tags: yammer

We are using the following method to generate a token to be used to make calls to the Yammer data export and REST apis. https://developer.yammer.com/introduction/

The token looks to be working for the most part, but it will expire ever 2 weeks for some Yammer instances. However, according to the documentation, I thought that the tokens generated in this way are not supposed to expire.

Are there any specific reason why tokens would be expiring every 2 weeks? I know that the user is not being deleted or deactivated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The access tokens are long lived and I have being using mine for about 4 months now. You want to double check to ensure that the user did not revoke the app's access from the "My Applications" page.